# Get members of event, who are statue "maybe" via FQL return NULL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like show all members of this facebook event, who are in status "maybe". Graph Api with FQL query get me NULL, but official facebook event has (1,898) "maybe" members. Where is mistake?

**Official FB event:**

https://www.facebook.com/events/175525179214102/

**FQL query via Graph API Explorer**

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20eid%20%3D%20175525179214102%20AND%20rsvp_status%20%3D%20'maybe'](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20eid%20%3D%20175525179214102%20AND%20rsvp_status%20%3D%20%27maybe%27)

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = 175525179214102 AND rsvp_status = 'maybe'
```

**Return:**

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Thank you for all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `rsvp_status = 'unsure'`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/